# batch search for documents elastic search

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using this hopelessly inefficient code to establish if a document is already indexed:

```
foreach (var entry in dic)
{
    var response = client.Search<Document>(s => s.Query(q => q.QueryString(d => 
    d.Query(string.Format("{0}", entry.Key)))));

    if (response.Documents.Count == 0)
    {
        not_found++;
    }
    else
    {
        found++;
    }
}
```

I wonder, if one could send several entry.Key in one batch rather than hitting the endpoint for every id (entry.Key)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure!

You can use a [`terms`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/terms-list-query-usage.html) filter:

```cs
client.Search<Document>(s => s.Query(
  q => q.Terms(
    c => c
      .Field(doc => doc.Id)
      .Terms(keys)))
```

If you are specifically looking for IDs, you can use the [`ids`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/ids-query-usage.html) filter:

```cs
client.Search<Document>(s => s.Query(
  q => q.Ids(c => c.Values(keys))
);
```

If you are only interested in whether or not the document(s) have been indexed, consider [limiting the returned fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/returned-fields.html) to only the ID field so you don't waste bandwidth returning the full document:

```cs
response = client.Search<Document>(s => s
  .Query(q => q.Ids(c => c.Values(keys))  // look for these IDs
  .StoredFields(sf => sf.Fields(doc => doc.Id))  // return only the Id field
);
```

Lastly, if you're only interested in the **number** of matching documents, then you can ask Elasticsearch to not return any results, and only use the response metadata to count how many documents matched:

```cs
response = client.Search<Document>(s => s
  .Query(q => q.Ids(c => c.Values(keys)))  // look for these IDs
  .Size(0)  // return 0 hits
);
found += response.Total; // number of total hits
```

Comment: thanks. could you please provide some code snippet to reduce bandwidth? Thanks.

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/returned-fields.html) has code examples for how to do this. I don't want to include specific ones because I don't know what your documents and mapping look like.